Best way to convert a Flink DataStream<POJOs> to a DataStream<RowData> for Apache Iceberg consumption
I am new to Flink and trying to use Flink with Kafka as data input and iceberg for storing the data.
Here are the steps I have done.

Read A Datastream of java POJOs from kafkaSource (with a Avro schema).
Convert the Datastream of POJOs to DataStream RowData by using MapFunction wrapper.
Send the DataStream of RowData to Iceberg using FlinkSink.

Everything works but My concern is with the way I am converting the DataStream of POJOs to DataStream of RowData. I have a complex and pretty big POJO reference and to convert it to RowData, I had to use .setField() method for each and handle each dataType transformation like StringData,Map, List etc.
I wanted to check here, if there is a better way to do this.

The Apache Hudi project has a AvroToRowDataConverters class that we've used in other projects to do something similar. Note the createRowConverter method needs a RowType, which you can get from Avro using Flink's AvroSchemaConverter, as in:
        DataType rowDataType =
                AvroSchemaConverter.convertToDataType(MyAvroGeneratedPOJO.SCHEMA$.toString());
        rowType = (RowType) rowDataType.getLogicalType();

If you don't want to pull in lots of Hudi code, it should be possible to clone the bits you need from AvroToRowDataConverters.
I think you could also use this approach of converting your POJO to binary data, and then deserializing back to a row, but it's going to be slower.

What you could do is to use similar approach as stated above. Convert your pojo through avro generic record into iceberg record.
For examples,
Lets prepare avro records on top of your pojo:
I use kotlin here
import org.apache.avro.reflect.Nullable
import org.apache.flink.formats.avro.typeutils.AvroSerializer
import org.apache.flink.core.memory.DataOutputSerializer
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericData
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord
import org.apache.avro.reflect.ReflectData
    
class SomeEntity {
    var email: String = ""
    @field:Nullable
    var name: String? = null
    @field:Nullable
    var second: Long? = null
}
    
inline fun <reified T> avroGeneric(value: T): GenericRecord {
        val serializer = DataOutputSerializer(1)
        AvroSerializer(T::class.java).serialize(value, serializer)
        return AvroSerializer(GenericData.Record::class.java, ReflectData.get().getSchema(T::class.java))
            .deserialize(DataInputDeserializer(serializer.sharedBuffer))
}

Then lets create a Flink Map Function that converts your avro record into iceberg based on avro schema. Basically you can reuse the one that is builtin into flink framework:
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord
import org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.MapFunction
import org.apache.flink.formats.avro.AvroToRowDataConverters
import org.apache.flink.formats.avro.AvroToRowDataConverters.AvroToRowDataConverter
import org.apache.flink.table.data.RowData
import org.apache.flink.table.types.logical.RowType

class AvroToRowDataMapper<T : GenericRecord> internal constructor(rowType: RowType) : MapFunction<T, RowData> {
    private val converter: AvroToRowDataConverter = AvroToRowDataConverters.createRowConverter(rowType)

    override fun map(genericRecord: T): RowData = converter.convert(genericRecord) as RowData
}

fun <T : GenericRecord> createAvroToRowMapper(avroSchema: String): MapFunction<T, RowData> {
    val dataType = AvroSchemaConverter.convertToDataType(avroSchema)
    val logicalType = TypeConversions.fromDataToLogicalType(dataType)
    val rowType = RowType.of(*logicalType.children.toTypedArray<LogicalType?>())
    return AvroToRowDataMapper(rowType)
}

Combine everything:
import org.apache.iceberg.flink.sink.FlinkSink
import org.apache.iceberg.flink.util.FlinkCompatibilityUtil

val entity = DummyEntity("test@test.com", null, 10L)
val avro = avroGeneric(entity)

val mapper = createAvroToRowMapper<GenericRecord>(avro.schema)

val avroStream = pojoStream.map { entity -> avroGeneric(entity) }
val rowDataStream = avroStream.map(mapper)

FlinkSink.forRowData(rowDataStream)

